Conference gave me a talk instead of a poster, but my results don't feel ready
PhD student in Astronomy here, roughly 2 years or so from graduation. I'm going to a significant conference in my subfield this week, and my abstract was accepted for a talk! I initially expected to get a poster slot, so I was excited as this will be my first time giving a talk at a conference (I've done a couple lunch seminars before).
However, now that it's only a few days out, I am extremely nervous. I didn't make nearly as much progress as I thought I would have made when I initially submitted the abstract, and I'm not particularly confident about my results.
I'm terrified that I'll go up there and folks will think "not only is that result wrong, very little substantial work has been done!" I worry that giving a talk about a potentially flawed work-in-progress will do more harm to my reputation than the visibility will do me good. And, with postdoc apps on the horizon, this makes me worried. Do I have reason to be concerned?

What does your advisor say?

@NateEldredge We haven't been able to meet much for the past few weeks due to both of us doing quite a bit of travel. However we did chat today -- she says my plots and slides look fine, but says I don't have much of a result. I tend to agree with her in that I didn't get as far as I wanted. I am also just not sure how much I trust what I do have.

But you should ask her the explicit question you've asked us - does she think this is this enough of a result to be worth presenting, or does she think you should withdraw?

Relax, give the talk, enjoy the experience.

To be honest with you, I can't remember a specific "bad talk" than the one I saw like last week. Really, the trick is in how you present your results. If you talk up "very little substantial work" then that's one thing. If you have some clarity about the meaningfulness of your work, that will reflect well on you. We all know research doesn't go as planned.

Even if someone regards your talk as "bad" and remembers that  when evaluating postdoc applications (unlikely, as you're still 2 years from graduation), they'll take into account that you'll  have corrected whatever made your talk "bad". You'll have done substantial work; you'll have good results; and your adviser and a committee will have determined that your work deserves a Ph.G.

Is it a typical practice in astronomy to submit an abstract about work one hasn’t yet completed and isn’t fairly confident in? Perhaps this uneasiness provides an opportunity to learn from?

@PaulTanenbaum Does your field not have a general division of talks: more complete results and posters: more in-progress work?

Yes, @AzorAhai-him-, but if I were submitting a proposal to describe work that was ongoing, I’d word it clearly enough that the organizers would be sure to understand its relative incompleteness. If they found the effort so interesting that they nonetheless cared to invite a break-out (or, gasp, plenary) talk, then although I might wonder about their judgment, I’d have no concern about presenting “potentially flawed work in progress.”

@Paul Sorry for the negative question, but do you mean your field does or does not have a distinction like I mentioned. || You seem to be taking a strong attitude that the OP did something wrong here ("I'd word it clearly enough"), and I'm not sure why. If you want to leave an answer that says "It sounds like the organizers found your work valuable," that would be appropriate. But, haven't we all had projects that don't go as well as we planned?

@AzorAhai-him-, my yes above meant, “Yes, my field does have such a division.” Of course we have all “had projects that don’t go as well as we planned,” and there isn’t the least shame in that. My only concern here is whether the OP may have oversold in their submission. If not, if they provided a candid assessment of the state of their project, then no problem.

My first suggestion is that you find a way to talk to your advisor, both about whether you should withdraw, and if not, what to say in the talk.
My next, and best, however, is that you be honest in any talk about the state of affairs. If you haven't reached conclusive results, then say so, and indicate that it is still a work is progress. Give the state of the study and what your current expectations are, assuming that is possible.
Even if it looks like the results will be negative, say so. Negative results can be as valuable as positive ones, if they redirect people away from failed approaches. What we learn is important, even if it isn't what we expected to learn.
Give some estimate about when more might be known, even if it is a bit uncertain. Plan on speaking with interested people after the talk, which can lead to future projects and collaborations. Have fun.
Note that with only a few days to go, it might not be possible to withdraw as it would leave a hole in the program. You might, however, inform the conference committee of your misgivings. Depending on the field, and the conference, this situation might be common enough to not be an issue.

Ultimately you have three options:

Give the talk. You can explain that your results are partial and/or preliminary. If you are feeling brave you can welcome feedback.
Write to the conference organisers explaining that you would really rather have a poster, and asking if they can accomodate you
Withdraw completely

The fact that the conference is only a few days away may limit option (2), as the conference organisers are less likely to be receptive to something that affects their programme at the last minute.
The only person who can give you really good advice on these options is your supervisor, because they know both your work and the norms for the conference. For example, at the conferences I go to it is fairly common to have talks about planned work, or work in progress, without results - but I don't know if this is the case at your venue.
Having said that:
If you give the talk, the best case is that it goes over better than you expect, and might yield long-term benefits. The likely worst case is that the audience is bored. Unless conferences in your field are much more vicious than mine, it is unlikely that anybody would hold it against you long term. So you probably have more to gain than to lose.
